# How to show in a Ceate Crud select only enabled fileds

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm starting to study Laravel and Backpack for Laravel.

In the current project i have two tables:

```
Group:
id
name
enabled

Manager:
id
name
group_id
```

In the Create New Mananger page the form shows a select with all groups in the table. There is a way to show only groups with enabled=1 ?

I tried to search in the Backpack documentation but I didn't find anything.

EDIT

This is the code in the ManagerCrudController

```
class ManagerCrudController extends CrudController
{
 public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Manager::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/manager');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('manager', 'managers');
    }
protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(ManagerRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('group_id');
        CRUD::field('name');
    }
}
```

This is the Group Model and the Manager Model

```
class Group extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'enabled',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'enabled' => 'integer',
    ];


    public function managers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Manager::class);
    }
}

class Manager extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'group_id',
        'name',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'group_id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Group::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste the code where you retrieve a group.

Comment: you have to show your controller code where you are getting your groups list.

Comment: have you set the relationship between models? please share the relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally found that I had to change the field in the ManagerCrudController in this way and now it works:

```
From this:
CRUD::field('group_id');

To this:
$this->crud->addField([  // Select
            'label'     => "Gruppo",
            'type'      => 'select',
            'name'      => 'group_id', // the db column for the foreign key

            // optional
            // 'entity' should point to the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            // defining entity will make Backpack guess 'model' and 'attribute'
            'entity'    => 'group',

            // optional - manually specify the related model and attribute
            'model'     => "App\Models\Group", // related model
            'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user

            // optional - force the related options to be a custom query, instead of all();
            'options'   => (function ($query) {
                 return $query->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->where('enabled', 1)->get();
             }), //  you can use this to filter the results show in the select
         ]);
```

Thanks to everybody.